# Скриншот всей страницы в selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

коллеги!
 Собственно в заголовке и вопрос. Как сделать скрин видимой части, я знаю. Ничего найти не могу, а то что нарыл, нерабочее. Буду благодарен за любой совет!

Comment: Посмотрите эти примеры скриншота: [всего окна](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/938c15184911c72309d233339d80b9634d469f30/selenium__examples/screenshot.py), [отдельных элементов](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/selenium__examples/screenshot_elements/main.py)

Comment: @gil9red  Спасибо. Буду пробовать!

Comment: Отпишитесь, пожалуйста, по результатам, а лучше как ответ оформите :)

Answer (score 0):

По первой ссылке скрин только видимой области. по второй падает: Сначала на FF ругается, потом на локаторы... сейчас разбираться не стал, так как нашел таки другой способ.
Через консоль разраба есть возможность в скринить ВСЕ окно. 
Спасибо за помощь. Если интересен мой способ, могу тут его описать подробно)

Comment: @gil9red Добрый день. Может подскажете, как сделать скрин всей страницы сайта БЕЗ selenium?